# Getting a value from yaml

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a yaml config file with that entries:

```
[...]
deploy:
- username: ext_username
- apikey: ext_apikey
[...]
```

Now i would like to read username and apikey and put them into two local variables.
How can i do that?

Comment: Please show us, what have you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to read the file and use the `YAML` module to parse its contents:

```
require "yaml"

config = YAML.load(File.read("path/to/config.yml"))
```

You can then access your configuration items from the parsed hash:

```
username = config["deploy"][0]["username"]
api_key = config["deploy"][1]["apikey"]
```

---

Note that you're making your `deploy` variable an array, which doesn't seem to be necessary in this case. Instead you could simplify it to:

```
deploy:
  username: ext_username
  apikey: ext_apikey
```

Accessing the values would then be done through:

```
username = config["deploy"]["username"]
api_key = config["deploy"]["apikey"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Easier than i thought.